# The [helpdesk] tag isn't helpful

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

If you look at [helpdesk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/helpdesk), most of the questions have nothing to do with helpdesks, or they are denoting a "helpdesk"-style question. I recommend that this tag be **deleted** because it does not have a clear purpose, nor are they useful in any way.

Comment: Those questions are posted on SU, and SU is the helpdesk.  How could you miss that?  All questions on SU should have a [helpdesk] tag as well as a `[SU]` tag, and probably a [question] tag.  They also share that they are in English, so they should have an [english] tag.  And since the questions will have at least those four tags, they should also have a [tag] tag.  That doesn't leave any tags for what the question is about, so we should increase the number of tags per question to 10.  And probably use one of those for the [increased-tags] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Done

Tag removed from all questions.

Questions about setting up a helpdesk service are off-topic for Super User. If the question has to do with helpdesk *software*, it *might* be on-topic for Server Fault, but remember not to migrate crap. In any case, this is a meaningless meta tag.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't we just rename the tag to "helpdesk-software" or something?

That way people who just want to ask a "helpdesk" style question will not use that tag.

EDIT: Or mitigate them to server fault!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's rather off-topic for SU, as what you're referring to is essentially server software. I would just remove the tag altogether.

Comment: +1. That's a fair point.